# How can i place % symbol after an interger

Tags: c, mplab

I need to print a string with an integer an the symbol % after it.

Here is what i try:

```
sprintf(txt, "%d",CurrentArrayValue,'%');
```

But my result is only my number. None symbol after that

Comment: This should have been covered in just about any beginners book.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'd wager that in a room containing 100 reasonably proficient C programmers, only 50 would know this.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- that can't possibly be true; or if it is, I am scared for our future.

Comment: @DavidBowling: I fear it is: and they will be funding our pensions!

Comment: @Bathsheba - Even if it is true, I consider part of true proficiency to be the ability to look it up.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You have a point, I used to refer to my library of C and C++ books (and a dusty FORTRAN one too) prior to t'internet.

Comment: I would not even have bothered to look it up and just used a '%c' to add the extra char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, simply a `%%` in the format string:

```
sprintf(txt, "%d%%",CurrentArrayValue * 100);
```

Your `'%'` is ignored by `sprintf` since your formatting string indicates to the function that only one additional argument is needed.

You have to multiply `CurrentArrayValue` by 100 yourself by the way: I slipped that in to the function parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

```
sprintf(txt, "%d%%",CurrentArrayValue);
```

This will do the trick.

From [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1) §7.21.6.1 C11 standard N1570

```
%
```

> A `%` character is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification shall be `%%`.